# RegionPlot shows different answers depending on domain

Tags: plotting, equation-solving

I'm having an issue where it seems like the region Mathematica shows depends on what the domain is (i.e. not just different parts of the same domain).

The code that gives me 2 intersecting lines $y = x$ and $y = 1 - x$ in the square $[0, 1] \times [0, 1]$:

```
Clear[polys, result];
polys = {
   (x^2 - x) - (y^2 - y), 
   (2 m*x - x - m + 1/2)^2 + (2 m*y - y - m + 1/2)^2 - 
    4 (m^2 - m) (x^2 - x)};
result = Resolve[Exists[{m}, polys == 0], Reals];
RegionPlot[result, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]
```

But, if I just change the y domain to end at $1/2$ instead of $1$, I get a completely empty plane, not just a zoomed in version of the original picture:

```
Clear[polys, result];
polys = {
   (x^2 - x) - (y^2 - y), 
   (2 m*x - x - m + 1/2)^2 + (2 m*y - y - m + 1/2)^2 - 
    4 (m^2 - m) (x^2 - x)};
result = Resolve[Exists[{m}, polys == 0], Reals];
RegionPlot[result, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1/2}]
```

If I change the $x$ and $y$ bounds in other situations I also get various different pictures. I know in this situation that the correct picture is in fact the two lines intersecting, but I won't know the answer in more complicated situations.

How do I "fix" this issue where Mathematica gives me different regions depending on what the $x$ and $y$ bounds are?

Comment: I'm suprised that your first `RegionPlot` shows something. Usually RegionPlot only shows 2D-regions I think.

Answer (score 3):

Usually `RegionPlot` cann't show 1D-regions!

```
cond = Simplify[result, {  1 >= x >= 0, 1 >= y >= 0}] /. Or -> List
(* {x == y, x + y == 1}*)
```

`ContourPlot`shows these lines in both domains

```
Row[{ContourPlot[ Evaluate[cond] , {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}],ContourPlot[ Evaluate[cond] , {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1/2}]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`RegionPlot` sometimes tries to discrete the object automatically,this is why it can draw both 1-D and 2-D region. But it seems that it doesn't always take effect,so we need to discrete the object manually or use `Region` etc.

```
polys = {(x^2 - x) - (y^2 - 
      y), (2 m*x - x - m + 1/2)^2 + (2 m*y - y - m + 1/2)^2 - 
    4 (m^2 - m) (x^2 - x)};
result = Resolve[Exists[{m}, polys == 0], Reals];
{Region[ImplicitRegion[result, {{x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}}]],
  Region[ImplicitRegion[
    result, {{x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1/2}}]]} // GraphicsRow
```

[image]

**Original**

One way is using `ImplicitRegion` and `DiscretizeRegion` before `RegionPlot`.

```
Clear[polys, result, reg1, reg2];
polys = {(x^2 - x) - (y^2 - 
      y), (2 m*x - x - m + 1/2)^2 + (2 m*y - y - m + 1/2)^2 - 
    4 (m^2 - m) (x^2 - x)};
result = Resolve[Exists[{m}, polys == 0], Reals];
reg1 = ImplicitRegion[result, {{x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}}];
reg2 = ImplicitRegion[result, {{x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1/2}}];
{RegionPlot[DiscretizeRegion[reg1]], 
  RegionPlot[DiscretizeRegion[reg2]]} // GraphicsRow
```

[image]